# A logistic problem about decision theory

Tags: self-study, decision-theory

Belows is the question and the solution for part c which is the part that i don't understand. Can someone explains to me? I don't quite get how it gets $3\over 7$ and why does it needs to?Any hint about that???

Transcribed from [two](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ckKk.png) [images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rI9Yk.png):

Dora Bender and Joey Mark graduated together at Business School. Both hope to open a coffee shop around the corner in the financial center. Using a system approach, Dora and Joey have identified three strategies. Strategy $1$ is to invest in a fairly expensive coffee brewer with high-quality coffee bean imported from Italy. In a favorable market, they should be able to obtain a net profit of $\$12,000$ in a month. If the market is unfavorable, they can lose $\$8,000$. Strategy $2$ is to purchase a less expensive brewer. In a favorable market, they could earn a return of $\$8,000$, whereas in an unfavorable market, they would incur a loss of $\$5,000$. The third strategy is to do nothing. Basically, Joey is a risk taker, but Dora is a risk avoider.

(a) What type of decision procedure should Joey use? What would Joey's decision be?

(b) Sketch the utility curve vs. monetary value for Dora and Joey.

(c) During the decision making period, Dora and Joey have been approached by a marketing firm. PriceAd Marketing, who claimed that they could provide technical analysis with certainty for the market condition for the coming year. Using the Expected Value of Perfect Information (EVPI) technique, determine the most Joey and Dora would be willing to pay for PriceAd?

$\begin{array}{}
\text{(c) }
&0 \le p \le \frac37\quad&\text{EVPI} = 5000 - 1000 p\\
&\frac37 \lt p \lt 1\quad&\text{EVPI} = 8000 - 8000 p\\
&p=0.5\quad&\text{EVPI} = \$4000
\end{array}$

Comment: This question will need modification to be answerable. First, please read our [faq] concerning homework questions. Next, edit the question to reflect what you have tried and where you have gotten stuck. Please recognize that it comes from a narrow specialized context in which "decision procedure" cannot possibly mean what it usually does: your class must be focusing on certain kinds of procedures and have in mind only one specific utility function. So you also need to provide some background about what kinds of answers might be expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How I learned to do EVPI is by finding the difference between the expected value with perfect information and the expected value with current information.

For the expect value with current information:

```
EV = $2,000
      => Strategy1
           => EV = 0.5*$12,000 + 0.5*-$8,000 = $2,000
              => P(FavMarket)  =0.5    => $12,000
              => P(UnfavMarket)=0.5    => -$8,000
      => Strategy2
           => EV = 0.5*$8,000 + 0.5*-$5,000 = $1,500
              => P(FavMarket)  = 0.5   =>  $8,000
              => P(UnfavMarket)= 0.5   => -$5,000
      => Strategy3                     =>  $0
```

For the expect value with perfect information:

```
EV = 0.5*$12,000 + 0.5*$0 = $6,000
      => P(FavMarket) = 0.5
           => EV = $12,000
             => Strategy 1   => $12,000
             => Strategy 2   => $8,000
             => Strategy 3   => $0
      => P(UnfavMarket) = 0.5
           => EV = $0
             => Strategy 1   => -$8,000
             => Strategy 2   => -$5,000
             => Strategy 3   => $0
```

So you have now EVPI = \$6,000 - \$2000 = $4,000

And I don't really know why you use 3/7

Comment: Sorry for the layout. It's easier to get it with a little graph, but I hope you get it.